# android, Method invoke problem when getting result

Tags: android, methods

I am try to use reflection to invoke the "List Camera.Parameters.getSupportedFocusModes()" function with the following codes:

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
Method method = params.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSupportedFocusModes", (Class[]) null);
Object o = method.invoke(params, (Object[]) null);
```

the log shows it does find the function, however, the result o is always null, why is that? Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Returned `[auto, infinity]`

Make sure that the device you are testing on is using **API Level 5** or higher and that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />` is added to the AndroidManifest.xml.

Here's the code I used.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
try
{
    Method method = params.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSupportedFocusModes", (Class[]) null);
    Object o = method.invoke(params, (Object[]) null);
    Log.i("Camera Test", o.toString());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering. 
the above code you used still returns nothing on my Desire.
However, surprisingly, Object o = method.invoke(params) worked. 
any idea why is that? >.<
Thank you again!

Comment: I think that Object o = method.invoke(params) is the correct way to call a method without arguments. Not sure why the other way worked for me and not for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "**getMethod**"
Below is the sample using the same.

```
Method method = this.getFirstActivity().getClass().getMethod("didReceive", null); 
method.invoke(this.getFirstActivity().getClass().newInstance(), null);
```